# How do I stop a door from swinging open without taking out the pins?

Tags: doors, door-frame

I have a door that swings open. If I open it a crack it will swing open the entire way. I want to be able to leave it at a certain angle and have it stay there.

Here is the problem, I cannot take out the pins (this is a door to my office I use several times per week, my boss said fix it any way you like but do NOT take it off the hinge and do NOT remove the pins), so I need something to possibly attach to it to keep it from swinging.

I noticed there are three holes drilled in both the top back of the door and the frame, it is like something was attached there before.

Is there some sort of device I can  attach to the door to keep it from swinging open or to control the angle at which it stays open?

thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I'd attach a "door friction stay"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your in a pickle with the boss's restrictions. Isherwood was right in reguards to the door framing being out of plumb. My suggestion would be to invest a couple of dollars for a rubber wedge type stopper,and put it under the door to hold it back where you want it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Office doors typically have closers to meet fire safety requirements. Sounds like one was removed, possibly due to failure. The problem is that either the wall or the door jamb are out of plumb, allowing gravity to have its way with the heavy door.

The only proper way to deal with it is with a closer and a swing-down stop. Everything else is hacky, and involves introducing friction to the swing. You can bend the pins, but that's a bandage that won't last. You can install something that drags on the floor, but that'll wear out or cause damage.

Get the office superintendent to fix it right with an adjustable industrial closer, and have a toe-operated flip-down stop installed to let you set the door where you like.

Comment: Thanks a lot! My boss doesn't get along with the maintenance crew, so we're basically left to our own devices when it comes to repairs. I noticed that my coworkers don't have closers, maybe this door always had problems even before I showed up 2 years ago. I will see if I can get my hands on an industrial closer.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not an "Approved" method.  If you set the door where you want to crack it at and take 2 hammers and stike the upper and lower parts of the hinge amd pin at the same time on all 3 hinges it will off set them and cause friction.  Make sure to tape cover door and frame since  you probably will hit them also. Again this is NOT a approved method just a olf country fix.